# Visual Studio Debugger 2010 - Can't Connect to webdev process

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've searched all over the internet for a situation that is similar to mine. Ive found nothing.

I have MS VS 2010 Pro on Windows 7.

My problem is that I cannot connect the debugger to the WebDev.WebServer40.EXE worker process.  If I click the green debug button, firefox (or IE) opens, but immediately displayed a "Cannot connect to server" and the VS acts as if the button was never pressed.
If I right click a file name and click "view in browser", everything works fine.  If I then try to attach to the process manually, the process is killed (watching the task manager) and I get the same error as if I hit the debug button.

Now, I can export my web application and open it with IIS under localhost.  When I do that, I can connect to the w2wp.exe worker process and debug that way.

Also, I can't debug any console apps.  Not screen appears.

There is no good information in the output window.

I can't find any good errors in the event viewer.

This all started recently.  Previously it worked fine.  The only thing I did in the last couple of days was uninstall and reinstall visual SVN.  Currently it is uninstalled.  I also did the full repair on Visual Studio to try and fix the issue.  I can't think I anything else to try...

(Note, I also have VS 2012 RC installed on the machine.  It gets the same exact issues).

**TLTR** VS Debugger can't connect to it's own worker process (the process crashes on attempting).  But it can connect to the IIS w3wp.exe worker process.  What the.....?

Comment: This may or may not be the issue but I had this happen to me once because my path variable got too long (thus visual studio dependent commands didn't work anymore). The error was never obvious but I was able to link it back to the path variable because of a recent install I had done. This probably won't help but its just a thought... Also, did you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950865/cannot-start-debugger-on-visual-studio-2010-f5-however-attach-to-process-d?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I haven't changed any path variables.

  I did see that post, but the problem tends to be different.  Plus, I don't have a firewall set up.

Comment: I just did a full reinstall of visual studio.  I ran ccCleaner to clean the registry.  The problem still persists.